# Javascript: Callback Injection Alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been reading that its not possible to inject a variable into a callback function.  Now with that in mind, does anyone have any work arounds to this problem?  I basically am trying to find a way to get a variable into an ajax callback function.  I have forms with a data-target which contains the div I want to load a success page into.

code

```
var ajaxfn = function (form) {return $.ajax(etc);};

/* on submit function */

ajaxfn("#someForm").done(function (data) {

    /* not sure how to get form data tag value */
    var target = $(this).data('targetdiv');

    if (data['status'] === 0) {$(target).load('success.html');}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `this` outside the done callback refers to the correct value, in that case

The problem is the execution context of the done callback is not the same as the function from which you are calling `ajaxfn`... you can use a closure variable in this case

```
var ajaxfn = function (form) {return $.ajax(etc);};

/ *on submit function */

var self = this;
ajaxfn("#someForm").done(function (data) {

    /* not sure how to get form data tag value */
    var target = $(self).data('targetdiv');

    if (data['status'] === 0) {$(target).load('success.html');}
});
```